# How to find the position ( coordinates ) of the next mouse left click in specific window handle

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, mouse

So I'm trying to find the next left click in a specific window, not the whole Screen,

Basically, I want to press a button then the application wait for the next left click in a specific window and then

it records its position in coordinates.

Also to make stuff clear, i’m coding a windows form in c#

Comment: Is the mouse click on the same application or external applications?

Comment: This describes how [Mouse Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/mouse-input) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your button use [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) to get the target `HWND`'s owning thread ID, then [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) to install a thread-specific [`WH_MOUSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644988(v=vs.85)) or [`WM_GETMESSAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644981(v=vs.85)) hook into that thread.

The hook will need to be implemented in a DLL if you want to hook a thread in another process.

The hook will tell you the `HWND` that is receiving the captured activity, and the coordinates of the mouse.  When you detect a `WM_LBUTTON(DOWN|UP)` message on the target `HWND`, you can then remove the hook.

Comment: [WM_LBUTTONDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown) reports the position in client-relative coordinates. Depending on the use case those coordinates would need to be appropriately translated.

Comment: @IInspectable In a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook, the raw message data would provide mouse coordinates relative to the receiving window's client area, yes. But the wrapping `MSG` provided by the hook would also supply screen coordinates. As would a `WH_MOUSE` hook.